# ms access: How to implement linear regression

Tags: ms-access, graph, vba

In excel it is possible to implement linear regression graph. But in ms access I could not find anything similar to excel. If there is nothing built in then how can I implement it.?

Answer (score 0):

just take the data that you generated in Excel for the line regression and export it to Access.Then click on chart to get the line regression! This is the basic method.